# How can I speed up this brute force addition algorithm in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, performance, algorithm, addition

I'm trying to learn a little more about algorithms and have built a simple one to see, using brute force, whether a target number can be made from a grid of randomly created numbers. I've done enough to check whether five of the grid numbers added together will create the target, which should be enough for the purpose I had in mind, but the process is VERY slow, around 11 seconds on the iOS simulator. How can I speed things up here? Is there a more efficient way to do this than using all the loops I'm using? Here's all my code, `GridNumber` is a simple `NSObject` subclass that contains two integers,  `number` and `tag`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      // 0. Set up target number.
      int random = arc4random() % 100 + 3;
      NSNumber *target = [NSNumber numberWithInt: random];

      // 1. Set up array of available numbers.
      NSMutableArray *grid = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      for (int i = 1; i < 48; i++) {
           GridNumber *number = [[GridNumber alloc] initWithRandomIntegerAndTag: i];
           [grid addObject: number];
      }

      if ([self canTarget: target BeMadeFromGrid: grid]) NSLog(@"--- SOLVEABLE!");
      else NSLog(@"--- UNSOLVEABLE!");
 }

 - (BOOL) canTarget: (NSNumber *) target BeMadeFromGrid: (NSArray *) grid
 {
      NSLog(@"TARGET NUMBER IS: %d", target.intValue);

      // 2. See if the target already exists first.
      for (GridNumber *firstValue in grid) {
           if (firstValue.number == target.intValue) {
                NSLog(@"SOLVEABLE IN 1: Grid already contains target!");
                return YES;
           }
      }

      // 3. Add elements once, see if any of those give the result.
      for (GridNumber *firstValue in grid) {
           for (GridNumber *secondValue in grid) {
                int result = firstValue.number + secondValue.number;
                if (result == target.intValue && firstValue.tag != secondValue.tag) {
                     NSLog(@"SOLVEABLE IN 2: Adding %d and %d creates target!", firstValue.number, secondValue.number);
                     return YES;
                }
           }
      }

      // 4. Add elements twice, see if any of those give the result.
      for (GridNumber *firstValue in grid) {
           for (GridNumber *secondValue in grid) {
                for (GridNumber *thirdValue in grid) {
                     int result = firstValue.number + secondValue.number + thirdValue.number;
                     if (result == target.intValue && firstValue.tag != secondValue.tag && firstValue.tag != thirdValue.tag && secondValue.tag != thirdValue.tag) {
                          NSLog(@"SOLVEABLE IN 3: Adding %d, %d and %d creates target!", firstValue.number, secondValue.number, thirdValue.number);
                          return YES;
                     }
                }
           }
      }

      // 5. And three times..
      for (GridNumber *firstValue in grid) {
           for (GridNumber *secondValue in grid) {
                for (GridNumber *thirdValue in grid) {
                     for (GridNumber *fourthValue in grid) {
                          int result = firstValue.number + secondValue.number + thirdValue.number + fourthValue.number;
                          if (result == target.intValue && firstValue.tag != secondValue.tag && firstValue.tag != thirdValue.tag && firstValue.tag != fourthValue.tag &&
                              secondValue.tag != thirdValue.tag && secondValue.tag != fourthValue.tag && thirdValue.tag != fourthValue.tag) {
                               NSLog(@"SOLVEABLE IN 4: Adding %d, %d, %d and %d creates target!", firstValue.number, secondValue.number, thirdValue.number, fourthValue.number);
                               return YES;
                          }
                     }
                }
           }
      }

      // 6. And four times..
      for (GridNumber *firstValue in grid) {
           for (GridNumber *secondValue in grid) {
                for (GridNumber *thirdValue in grid) {
                     for (GridNumber *fourthValue in grid) {
                          for (GridNumber *fifthValue in grid) {
                               int result = firstValue.number + secondValue.number + thirdValue.number + fourthValue.number + fifthValue.number;
                               if (result == target.intValue && firstValue.tag != secondValue.tag && firstValue.tag != thirdValue.tag && firstValue.tag != fourthValue.tag &&
                                   firstValue.tag != fifthValue.tag && secondValue.tag != thirdValue.tag && secondValue.tag != fourthValue.tag && secondValue.tag != fifthValue.tag &&
                                   thirdValue.tag != fourthValue.tag && thirdValue.tag != fifthValue.tag && fourthValue.tag != fifthValue.tag) {
                                    NSLog(@"SOLVEABLE IN 5: Adding %d, %d, %d, %d and %d creates target!", firstValue.number, secondValue.number, thirdValue.number, fourthValue.number, fifthValue.number);
                                    return YES;
                               }
                          }
                     }
                }
           }
      }

      // 7. This is if it can't be made.
      return NO;
 }
```

Comment: Paralelize the tasks into multiple threads.

Comment: @Shark I was thinking more in terms of the efficiency of the algorithm itself.

Comment: In that case simply rewrite it, as to put it bluntly - it's plain garbage. you're doing O(n), followed by O(n^2) then O(n^3) then O(n^4) only to end up with O(n^5) ... You would save time if you only tried the last variant, but it seems like you're trying to find a combination out of a set that can add up to a number, right? Why not explore the mathematical background of the problem first before tackling the code? If you did, you would find that this subset-sum problem is NP-hard is in no way something to attempt 'while learning algorithms'.

Comment: @Shark I have no idea what O(n) means, I'm new to algorithm design and I'd like some specific pointers on thinking to rewrite the algorithm, not something conceptual that I don't understand.

Comment: In that case read up on algorithms as there is no point in discussing algorithm design and efficiency if you do not yet grasp the basest of basic concepts such as `the big O` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Comment: To put it simply, given a `grid of 5 elements` the first loop which is O(n) executes up to 5 times. Second, which is O(n^2) executes up to `5*5 = 25` times... Excercise is left to the reader to figure out why O(n^5) is bad.

Comment: @Shark Frankly, that's not a helpful response at all. I'm trying to approach this from a programming perspective, not that of a computer science student studying theoretically, and I'm trying to understand the specifics of what issues there are in my code. Theoretical concepts seem a thousand miles away from what I'm doing here to me at the moment.

Comment: As a programmer to a programmer, you should know how many iterations to expect before you write it, and how to cut them down. If you think you've minimized the number of iterations down to the least possible  minimum and it's still veery slow - revisit your design.

Comment: @Shark I'm aware that a lot of iterations could occur, but I'm asking how I would limit that number, that was the very basis of the question. What other approaches are available for this problem? "revisiting my design" is exactly why I've made this question here.

Comment: You've picked the wrong problem to try and find trivial solutions, it's all I'm saying :D

Comment: @Shark You're saying it in "Don't ever bother." way. What makes you think I'm looking for a trivial solution? I'm asking for advice on how to proceed programmatically, and all you seem to be telling me is "you can't do this." It's somewhat frustrating.

Comment: Lukech, I told you to explore the background of the problem and you want to jump right into code. If you really feel confident, you can try writing heuristics or do some dynamic programming gymnastics OR even just try out the O(N^5) solution without the previous four cases and all of those will cut down your execution time.

However, try it out on paper by hand. You will see it's somewhat hard to do even on a test example. I'm not saying "don't bother" - i'm saying ***"know your enemy before you attack"***.

Comment: But your attitude of "I don't know what O(n) means and I want to solve this by code, I don't need theory" is very devaluating to my suggestion as well. Why bother speaking to a dense wall. If you want to code and just code - go ahead and code it. If you want to understand that coding this won't be straightforward at all - you might look into combinatorial solutions, which could be based on a Monte Carlo simulation. Essentially 'trying out until you make it' for a while, much like you're doing now. If you do pull it off, you could prove Goldbach's conjecture as a byproduct.

Comment: @Shark: This "plain garbage" is also called "iterative deepening" and (in a more general form, where recursion is used to allow any number of elements to be added instead of limiting to 5) is a good strategy for searching large spaces.  Stop being rude, and before you accuse someone else of doing something stupid, make sure it's actually stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the idea of @torquestomp, here is some C code I was able to put together quickly. For a grid of 48 numbers (in the range of 1 to 21) looking for a target less than 203 it hardly ever takes more than a few hundreths of a second to run. The runtime will increase as you allow for longer solutions (more than 5 or 6 numbers). Note that I have not fully tested this function. The times reported are on a Mac. On the iPhone they will be slower.

Edit: if you sort the list of numbers in descending order you should find the "optimal" (fewer numbers in sum) solutions first.

```
typedef void(^execution_block_t)(void);

double time_execution(execution_block_t aBlock);
double time_execution(execution_block_t aBlock)
{
    uint64_t time0 = mach_absolute_time();
    aBlock();
    uint64_t time1 = mach_absolute_time();
    return (double)(time1 - time0)/NSEC_PER_SEC;
}

static int totalTests = 0;

int findPartialSum(int target, int *grid, int gridCount, int startIndex, int *solution, int depth, int maxDepth)
{
    for (int i=startIndex;  i<gridCount;  i++) {

        int newTarget = target - grid[i];
        totalTests++;

        if (newTarget == 0) {
            solution[depth-1] = i;
            return 1;
        }

        if (newTarget > 0 && depth < maxDepth) {
            int found = findPartialSum(newTarget, grid, gridCount, i+1, solution, depth+1, maxDepth);
            if (found > 0) {
                solution[depth-1] = i;
                return found + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        static const int gridSize = 48;
        static const int solutionSize = 5;

        int *solution = calloc(sizeof(int), solutionSize);
        int *grid     = calloc(sizeof(int), gridSize);
        int  target   = arc4random_uniform(200) + 3;

        for (int i=0;  i<gridSize;  i++)
            grid[i] = arc4random_uniform(20) + 1;

        NSMutableArray *numbers = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i=0;  i<gridSize;  i++)
            [numbers addObject:@(grid[i])];

        NSLog(@"\nTarget = %d\nGrid = %@", target, [numbers componentsJoinedByString:@","]);

        __block int count = 0;
        double elapsedTime = time_execution(^(void) {
            count = findPartialSum(target, grid, gridSize, 0, solution, 1, solutionSize);
        });

        NSLog(@"Looking for solution with up to %d numbers", solutionSize);
        if (count > 0) {

            [numbers removeAllObjects];
            for (int i=0;  i<count;  i++)
                [numbers addObject:@(grid[solution[i]])];

            NSLog(@"Found solution with %d numbers: %@", count, [numbers componentsJoinedByString:@","]);

        } else {
            NSLog(@"No solution found");
        }

        NSLog(@"After looking at %d possible sums",totalTests);
        NSLog(@"Elapsed time was %fs", elapsedTime);

        free(solution);
        free(grid);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Some sample outputs:

```
Target = 159
Grid = 16,18,19,6,18,5,12,7,7,4,18,3,7,13,10,19,7,14,19,6,16,4,8,4,3,17,11,16,5,8,18,9,4,13,14,8,17,18,13,5,20,14,4,5,13,20,17,1
Looking for solution with up to 5 numbers
No solution found
After looking at 1925356 possible sums
Elapsed time was 0.014727s


Target = 64
Grid = 4,6,1,1,13,12,15,10,11,6,18,6,8,2,15,3,18,5,20,1,3,12,20,3,18,5,1,12,15,14,2,20,9,1,14,9,6,1,2,10,12,7,7,4,2,12,20,6
Looking for solution with up to 5 numbers
Found solution with 5 numbers: 4,6,18,18,18
After looking at 7271 possible sums
Elapsed time was 0.000048s
```

Answer (score 2):

This is known as the [Subset-Sum Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), and it is known to be NP-hard, so you are out of luck if you're looking for a really efficient solution.  NP-hard means that there is no known polynomial-time (i.e., fast) solution with regards to the size of the input (the number of numbers in the grid).  An understanding of big-Oh notation is rudimentary to taking advantage of this knowledge, so that seems like a good place to start.

However, since you are using only positive integers, and the target number is always in the range [3,102], a pseudo-polynomial-time solution is available through the use of Dynamic Programming.  As @Shark has mentioned, this is probably the thing you really want to focus on for now - if you don't understand the basics of recursive problem solving, tackling a known NP-hard problem right off the bat isn't the best idea ;)

In pseudo-code, you want to do something like this:

```
Define array on [0,102] representing reachable numbers.  Set 0 to be reachable
for each NSNumber in grid:
    Looping upwards, for every reachable target in [3,102], set target + NSNumber to be reachable too
    If the sum exceeds 102, cut the loop
Return true if, after checking all numbers, target is reachable
```

This generalized algorithm runs in O(N*M) time for positive integers, where N is the number of numbers in the grid, and M is the maximum possible target.  For N = 48 and M = 102, this should perform way better than the O(N^5) algorithm you are currently using

Comment: I'm struggling to understand a lot of what you've said here. The pseudocode doesn't make a lot of sense to me, and I'm not sure what dynamic programming is. My code should indicate that reusing numbers is NOT allowed, that's what all the &&s and tags are for, ensuring that the same number in the grid isn't used twice.

Comment: thumbs up for mentioning NP-hardness :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try generating a set containing all combinations of additions, and checking whether your target number is in that set (list). Generating such a set would take a long time, but that would give you the benefit of looking up more than one target against the same set in O(logn) - making it more efficient for running multiple queries against your grid.

Instead of re-adding the numbers and essentially re-generating the set every time you want to check a new target against the same grid of numbers.

Comment: the idea is not a bad one but can become prohibitively expensive to compute in terms of memory. For a 5 number solution there are about 200M possibilities. Even if cut this number by 4 by truncating branches you would still get 50M entries in the set.

Comment: Although you attack the OP for writing "plain garbage" and being ignorant, you're apparently not aware that the OP's approach goes by the name "iterative deepening" and is not only a valid but also a smart strategy for tackling hard search problems (e.g. chess).  The fact that e.g. every combo of 4 numbers is regenerated when trying every combo of 5 numbers doesn't matter in theory or practice, because the former loop (and all the loops preceding it) only takes O(1/n) as long as the final one anyway.  It's only as "bad" as adding an extra O(1) step to an O(n) algorithm.